# auto-renewable subscription renew?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storekit

there I am new to auto-renewable subscriptions.
I have implemented the subscription. My problem is if the user buys the subscription for the first time app will go premium. but in any case, his second payment is not happened because of any reason. how did I know that the payment was not successful and or successful? I followed the WWDC tutorial for in-app purchases. implemented with storekit 2.

```
func purchase(_ product: Product) async throws -> Transaction? {
        //Begin a purchase.
        let result = try await product.purchase()
        
        switch result {
        case .success(let verification):
            let transaction = try checkVerified(verification)
            print(transaction)
            print(transaction.expirationDate as Any)
            
           
            
            //Deliver content to the user.
            await updatePurchasedIdentifiers(transaction)
            
            if !purchasedIdentifiers.isEmpty{
                IAP.premiumEndDate = transaction.expirationDate
            }
            //Always finish a transaction.
            await transaction.finish()
            
            return transaction
        case .userCancelled, .pending:
            return nil
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IAP's apple generate a receipt against each transaction containing a lot of information like a digital signature to validate the purchase, history of transactions including successful and unsuccessful transaction, the current status of the subscription, expiry date, and much more.

You have to validate the receipt by fetching from the Apple server to get all this information. you can check [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store) to know how to fetch receipt data.

for validation, we can go with 2 techniques

1. On-device validation(validation on the device locally if you're not using server in your app)
2. Server-side validation(Recommended)

you can read more about choosing receipt validation technique [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/choosing_a_receipt_validation_technique).

When you fetch receipt it will give you a **receiptData**  and you will convert it to **base64EncodedString** and hit API for receipt.

For **SandBox** use https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt and for **production** use https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt. pass it two parameters Receipt base64String and **App-Specific Shared Secret** you can find App-Specific Shared Secret on App store on the top right corner of your in-app purchases list.

You will receive a response containing all information about the subscription.

Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/705/) video of title **Engineering Subscriptions** from **WWDC 2018**. This video is really helpful in understanding subscriptions.

Comment: hi, @Naqeeb Ahmed thank you for your answer, and one thing is your link [1] and [2] are not working.
if you fix then that helps alot.

Comment: updated please check now

Comment: Naqeeb brother share some code. it will be a lot helpful. Thankyou

Comment: please check this link for code https://mobikul.com/in-app-subscription-receipt-validation-in-ios-using-swift/

Comment: I am using storeKit 2. do i have to do this